# Socket.io Chat application TypeError: Cannot read property 'room' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

There is an issue with sudden stoppage and disappearing of chat messages during users chatting.
It can only get to normal once browser is refreshed. Socket.io Chat aplication.

Here is the error code:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'room' of undefined
at Socket.socket.on.msg (/home/firszmuu/beyok.firstcla.net/server.js:51:16)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at /home/firszmuu/beyok.firstcla.net/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
/home/firszmuu/beyok.firstcla.net/server.js:51
io.to(user.room).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, msg));
           ^
```

here is the users.js file

```
// Join user to chat
function userJoin(id, username, room) {
  const user = { id, username, room };

  users.push(user);

  return user;
}

// Get current user
function getCurrentUser(id) {
  return users.find(user => user.id === id);
}

// User leaves chat
function userLeave(id) {
  const index = users.findIndex(user => user.id === id);

  if (index !== -1) {
    return users.splice(index, 1)[0];
  }
}

// Get room users
function getRoomUsers(room) {
  return users.filter(user => user.room === room);
}

module.exports = {
  userJoin,
  getCurrentUser,
  userLeave,
  getRoomUsers
};
```

Comment: Check the 'user' variable. The error states that it is undefined

Comment: Can you give us some of your code, specifically where you're defining the user and the rooms. We cant guess how you've done it. [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the users.js file code